# MongoDb query Vs engine ressources

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I learned some web programming during the last 2 years but i know nothing about computer hardware and how it actually deal with my functions so sorry if my question is silly.

I built a online pilot logbook. I use Mongodb for my database and i have 1 schema for users and another one for flight where each flight is one entry.
I have a overview page where i can see the total flight time for the last week, month, 90 days and 365 days. So my function query the database asking for all flight where user id is XXX and the date is today minus 7 days, minus 30 days, minus 90 days and minus 365 days.

So my question is  : Everytime i load this page my function will go 4 times over each entry in the database to check if it fit my query, Does it take a lot of ressources ?

I know that my case is not big with only a few thousand entries in my database but i just want to build something efficient and know if i should care about this stuff or if it s such a small part of all the computation in a full webapp that it doesn't really matters ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample input data, sample of desired result and what you have tried so far.